# Determine the radius of the circle knowing that...

Tags: geometry, circles

I have such a problem: determine the radius of a circle in which you know that two chords of lengths $9$ and $17$ intersect in a point, and that the distance between the middle points of these chords is $5$.
[image]

Comment: What I did is: I expressed the distances between the center of the circle and the respective middle points of chords using the radius of the circle. Next, I do not know what to do!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me that this problem has a solution, if one knows nothing about the point of intersection of the two chords.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the triangle with side lengths 9, 10, 17 and its circumcircle. Then you have a possible solution. It is not unique, though.